# Pandas - merge many rows into one

Tags: python, pandas

with this:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('lyrics.csv', delimiter = '\t', quoting = 3)
```

I print my dataset in this fashion:

```
                                   lyrics,classification
0       "I should have known better with a girl like you
1               That I would love everything that you do
2                        And I do, hey hey hey, and I do
3                                          Whoa, whoa, I
4                    Never realized what I kiss could be
5                           This could only happen to me
6                           Can't you see, can't you see
7               That when I tell you that I love you, oh
8      You're gonna say you love me too, hoo, hoo, ho...
9                          And when I ask you to be mine
10                      You're gonna say you love me too
11          So, oh I never realized what I kiss could be
12       Whoa whoa I never realized what I kiss could be
13                                       You love me too
14                                    You love me too",0
```

but what I really need is to have all thats between `""` per row. how do I make this conversion in `pandas`?

Comment: is this the entire dataset, or are there multiple songs in the same csv?  Do you want slashes for line breaks (You love me too / You love me too) or just spaces (You love me too You love me too)

Comment: it seems that your delimiter is the comma instead of a tab, no?

Comment: @nbeuchat is probably right, just try `dataset = pd.read_csv('lyrics.csv', quoting = 2)`.  That should give you a dataframe with one row and two columns: lyrics (with embedded line returns in the string) and classification (0).  But without your dataset it's hard to tell.

Comment: this works. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution that worked for OP (from comments):

Fixing the problem at its source (in `read_csv`):

> @nbeuchat is probably right, just try
>
> `dataset = pd.read_csv('lyrics.csv', quoting = 2)`
>
> That should give you a dataframe with one row and two columns: lyrics (with embedded line returns in the string) and classification (0).

#### General solution for collapsing series of strings:

You want to use [pd.Series.str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'lyrics':pd.Series(['happy birthday to you',
                                            'happy birthday to you',
                                            'happy birthday dear outkast',
                                            'happy birthday to you'])})    
dataset['lyrics'].str.cat(sep=' / ')   
# 'happy birthday to you / happy birthday to you / happy birthday dear outkast / happy birthday to you'
```

The default `sep` is `None`, which would give you `'happy birthday to youhappy birthday to youhappy ...'` so pick the `sep` value that works for you.  Above I used slashes (padded with spaces) since that's what you typically see in quotations of songs and poems.

You can also try `print(dataset['lyrics'].str.cat(sep='\n'))` which maintains the line breaks but stores them all in one string instead of one string per line.